# Why can I not set form location property this way?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

My application has two forms. I want to position one form in front of another. I want to understand why this code does not work:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Location = New Point(200, 200)
    Form2.Location = New Point(200, 200)
    Form2.BringToFront()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Form2.Visible = True
    Me.Text = Form2.Location.X
End Sub
End Class
```

When I run the code, the second form is positioned in a random place on the screen.
If I remove the *Form2.Visible* statement:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Location = New Point(200, 200)
    Form2.Location = New Point(200, 200)
    Form2.BringToFront()
End Sub
Private Sub Form1_Shown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Me.Text = Form2.Location.X
End Sub
End Class
```

The second form seems to be positioned correctly, but alas, it is not visible.

I am sure, there are workarounds. I just want to understand why such a simple thing does not work as expected.

Comment: Several bad practices here, but the core reason is that you forgot to set the form's StartPosition property to Manual.

Comment: Hi, Hans! Thanks for the help, it worked! But why does the first form show in the right place? Could you also elaborate on bad practices, please?

Comment: That's a question that requires a book, we don't write them around here.  The best way to discover this by yourself is by writing code in C# for a while, it will not let you get away with this kind of programming style.  The brain transplant is going to hurt badly and you'll lose a year of your life but you'll be a much better programmer after that and thoroughly understand the difference between classes and objects.

Comment: I have books. Could you refer me to the right chapter? I do not have a year to write code in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans mentions in the comments, you need to set [Form.StartPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to [FormStartPosition.Manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in order for the form to read the location that you set. For more information on how and why it is this way see [this question on StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225741/how-do-you-set-the-startposition-of-a-windows-forms-form-using-code).