# Form location relative to another form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a button on a form "Form1", when users click this button, another form "Form2" will pop up. How can I adjust Form2's location so that it is at the center of the Form1 when it pops up? I tried adjusting the location properties but it is not working.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does it mean "I tried adjusting the location properties but it is not working"? It's like asking why you PC does not power up without saying anything other,

Comment: Is Form2 shown at all?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `StartPosition` property of `Form2` to `CenterParent` and show the form using

```cs
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.ShowDialog();
```

If you don't want to show the form as dialog follow the confirmed answer of this question:

[How do you set the StartPosition of a Windows Forms form using code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225741/how-do-you-set-the-startposition-of-a-windows-forms-form-using-code)

Comment: Thanks Guido, I have already set the StartPosition property of Form2 to CenterParent. Where do I need to put the code Form2.ShowDialog()?

Comment: Here is the code in my form:                                       namespace  nyNameSpace
{
    public partial class frmMapping : Form
    {
        public Dictionary<string, string> columns;
        public frmMapping()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();
            columns = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

Comment: inside the button to show the form you already wrote some code similar to form2.Show(); to open the form, change that.

Comment: I had gridview in form2 and as soon as I change the code from Form2.Show to Form2.ShowDialog(), the gridview in the form disappeared. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Without see your code is not possible to know why this gridview disappeared.